# Как правильно захватить скриншот программно?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть окно текстового редактора, сделанного на `swing`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу распечатать текст на принтере, но это сложно, поэтому решил печатать картинкой. Для этого в `Printable` написал код:

```
     Printable printable = new Printable() {
   @Override
   public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

       if (pageIndex > 0) {
           return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
       } else {
           int pageWidth = (int) pageFormat.getWidth();
           JTextPane pane = scrollPaneList.get(tabs.getSelectedIndex()).getTextPane();

           textColor = Color.BLACK;

            try {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame.add(panel);
                JTextPane printPane = new JTextPane();
                panel.add(printPane);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                printPane.setStyledDocument(pane.getStyledDocument());
                printPane.setPreferredSize(pane.getPreferredSize());
                frame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);


                Robot robot = new Robot();
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(frame.getX(),frame.getY(),pane.getWidth(),pane.getHeight());
                BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("screen.png"));
                //graphics.drawImage(img, 10,10,(int)pageFormat.getWidth(),(int)pageFormat.getHeight(), null);

                }
            catch (AWTException ex){}
            catch (IOException ex){}
            catch (Exception ex){
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }



           }
           return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
       }

     };
```

он создает еще один `JFrame` только с тем текстовым полем, вкладка которого открыта. Вот скриншот этого окна сделанный мной вручную:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот файл `screen.png`, созданный программно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо `robot` захватывает окно в момент, когда оно еще не полностью отресовалось `swing`из-за этого и получается такая белиберда. Как "Задержать захват скриншота" что ли? Не знаю как сформулировать этот вопрос, но надеюсь Вы меня поняли. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал отдельный метод для того, чтобы захватить скрин:

```
     public static BufferedImage getScreenComponent(Component component) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            component.getWidth(),
            component.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
    component.paint( image.getGraphics() );
    return image;
}
```

И немного переписал `Printable.print()`:

```
   Printable printable = new Printable() {
   @Override
   public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

       if (pageIndex > 0) {
           return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
       } else {
           int pageWidth = (int) pageFormat.getWidth();
           JTextPane pane = 
          scrollPaneList.get(tabs.getSelectedIndex()).getTextPane();
          try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);


                Robot robot = new Robot();
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(pane.getX(),pane.getY(),pane.getWidth(),pane.getHeight());
                BufferedImage img =  mainWindow.getScreenComponent(pane);
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("screen.png"));
                graphics.drawImage(img, 10,10,(int)pageFormat.getWidth(),(int)pageFormat.getHeight(), null);

                }
            catch (AWTException ex){}
            catch (IOException ex){}
            catch (Exception ex){
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Итог файл screen.png:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно печатать.